# GitHub: Unable to delete main branch from remote repository after changing default branch to master

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am unable to delete main branch from my remote repository after changing my default branch to master.

I made a repository on github and pushed the branch named master  from my local repository to it. Then i changed the default branch to master as it contained files i wanted to keep and remove the "main" branch but the delete icon isnt responding.

[image]

the option to delete main branch is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see that tiny shield icon?

[image: Highlighted image]

It means you have branch protection active.
You need to allow deletions.

[image: unchecked deletion option]

You will find the active rules at `<your-repository-link>/settings/branches`.